# what is facebook app's user ID to complete wordpress widget?

Tags: iphone, facebook, wordpress, widget

help me
I start my wordpress web site about 2 days ago 
I enabled facebook sharing post auto by a widget in my theme
in this widget I have 4 field to enter the true optional to share my post auto 
1- USER ID
2-App ID
3-App Secret 
4-Number of post to show 
I enter 2 , 3 , 4 ( create a facebook app and enter the app ID and secret )
but I don't know what the USER ID is and how can I find it 
I try my facebook user name , or the email I create my faceboo account but none of them was true to complete
help me please 
what is USER ID of facebook app or account to complete it ?
Great thanks
Regards :
Raha

Answer (score 1):

Visit the Facebook page that you want to use:

```
http://www.facebook.com/youruser
```

Then change the url to:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/youruser
```

You will see the ID.